# How to calculate the equivalent mass of Na2S2O3?

Tags: equilibrium, stoichiometry, titration

Let us consider the following reaction

$$\ce{I2 + 2 Na2S2O3 -> 2 NaI + Na2S4O6}$$

Now, in order to calculate the equivalent mass of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$, first I need to calculate it's $n$-factor which turns out to be $0.5$ because the oxidation state of $\ce{S}$ in $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ is $+2$ whereas in $\ce{Na2S4O6}$ it is $+2.5$.And the $n$-factor of $\ce{I2}$ is $1$. So, the equivalent mass of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ is

$$\frac{\text{molecular mass}}{0.5}$$
And Iam confused with the following half-reactions:
$$\ce{I2 +2e->2I-}$$
$$\ce{2S2O3^{2-}->S4O6^{2-} +2e}$$
I appreciate any help in order to solve a problem using milliequivalents?

Comment: The first and third reactions are not balanced in atoms.

Answer (score 2):

N-factor Is the change of atom oxidation state **multiplied** by number of atoms changing this state.

Therefore, n-factor of $\ce{I2}$ is $2$,
 n-factor of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ is $1$.

So, equivalent mass of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ is equal to its molar mass, for molecular iodine it is half of its molar mass.

Comment: excuse me: Is the equivalent mass of $\ce{KIO3}$ equal 5.$$\ce{KIO3 + 5 KI + 3 H2SO4 -> 3 I2 + 3 K2SO4 + 3 H2O}$$

Comment: Well, this is somewhat tricky. For the mentioned reaction, releasing iodine, the equivalent mass is M/5. But if the iodine is just an intermediate product to be titrated by Na2S2O3, the equivalent mass is M/6. As in the former, the oxidation number change is by 5, in the latter by 6.